# Anomalize Package in R -> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots)

Tags: r, tibbletime

After looking at all the related post, I have yet to find an acceptable working solution. Thus, I decided to try and ask again!

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date

> test_long$Date <- as.Date(test_long$Date, "%m-%d-%Y")
>
> test_long %>%
>   +   time_decompose(count) %>%
>   +   anomalize(remainder) %>%
>   +   time_recompose() %>%
>   +   plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol=3, alpha_dots = 0.25)
>
> Note: Index not ordered. tibbletime assumes index is in ascending order. Results may not be as desired.
>
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: Only year, quarter, month, week, and day periods are allowed for an index of class Date.
>
> str(test_long$Date)
>    Date[1:5719], format: "2016-01-27" "2016-01-28" "2016-01-29" "2016-01-30" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-01" "2016-02-02" "2016-02-03" "2016-02-04" "2016-02-05" "2016-02-06" ...

I apologize in advance if this post isn't sufficiently clear. This is my first post.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: test_long <- as.data.frame(data %>%
  group_by(date,acc_id) %>%
  summarise(count = as.numeric(n_distinct(d_id))) %>%
  ungroup())

test_long$acc_id <- as.character(test_long$acc_id)

test_long <- test_long %>% 
  tibbletime::as_tbl_time(index = date)


test_long %>%
  time_decompose(count) %>%
  anomalize(remainder) %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol=3, alpha_dots=0.25)